# How to know when user copied something to clipboard in android?

Tags: android, copy-paste

Is there any event that i can handle in android when user copied something to clipboard?

For example, When user clicked copy in the android system show a toast that "You did it"

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

You can use `OnPrimaryClipChangedListener` from `ClipboardManager` class in Android.

Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html#addPrimaryClipChangedListener(android.content.ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener))

EDIT:
Example:

```
class ClipboardListener implements ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener
{
   public void onPrimaryClipChanged()
   {
      // use getPrimaryClip() to get the data or simply display a toast
   }
}

ClipboardManager clipBoard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipBoard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener( new ClipboardListener() );
```

Comment: i should use intentservice for doing this? but nothing raised when user copy something

Comment: what did you try exactly?

Comment: I put this eventhandler inside my intentservice handleIntent and i went to my browser and selected something and copied that but the event does'nt raised.

Comment: did you add the listener to the ClipBoardManager object?

Comment: i am new to android programming. do you have a tutorial for doing this?